# Terminal move cursor with mouse in any way?

Tags: terminal

Is there any way at all to use the mouse cursor to move the cursor in terminal, like click where you want it and press a key to move it there?

This is one of the most annoying things I've ever found using the terminal

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will move to the beginning of the line but sometimes these commands are so long

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try *option*-click, that is, click with <kbd>option</kbd> pressed.

This works on the command line and also in screen editors, such as `vi` and `nano`.

*option*-click just sends the appropriate escape sequences to move the cursor to anywhere in the terminal screen. (To see this working, try it with `cat`.)

Comment: Didn't know that, wonder if there is a way to make this work in iTerm.

Comment: @Gerry, ah, finally a feature that Terminal has that iTerm hasn't!

Comment: @Gerry, see [Option + click in iTerm](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42825/option-click-in-iterm).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me? Im holding the `option` button and then clicking on a specific position but instead of taking me to that position it will load the previously ran command!? Im using yosemite and a 2015 macbook pro.