# How to enable iTerm 2's Option-Click feature? (Not duplicated)

Tags: iterm

In its document (https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html), it reads "If enabled, option-click will move the cursor to where the mouse pointer is. If you install shell integration, this will be well-behaved at the shell prompt by not sending up and down arrow keys." But it seems like when I do Options-Click it just goes to last command (arrow up).

This answer here is no longer a solution - deprecated, and the source code is removed ([Option + click in iTerm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42825/option-click-in-iterm)), and the thread should be removed/archived.

Comment: While the answer in [Option + click in iTerm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42825/option-click-in-iterm) may be out of date, Ask Different does not archive or remove once correct but now legacy information. Instead modify the original question, place a bounty, or down vote the now incorrect answer.

Comment: See also https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-should-we-manage-questions-that-have-very-different-answers-per-version-of-m (even if it is not macOS as such in this case).