# unknown option: mode-mouse with iterm, tmux

Tags: terminal, mouse, iterm, tmux

I've reset my computer and now tmux is complaining about my `.tmux.conf` having these directives:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window off
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

with these errors:

```
/Users/mdurrant/.tmux.conf:24: unknown option: mode-mouse                  [0/0]
/Users/mdurrant/.tmux.conf:25: unknown option: mouse-select-pane
/Users/mdurrant/.tmux.conf:26: unknown option: mouse-resize-pane
/Users/mdurrant/.tmux.conf:27: unknown option: mouse-select-window
```

So I have to comment them out, but then my mouse doesn't work in tmux, which is a pain.

How can I enable the mouse in iTerm2 with tmux?

This works on my other Mac.

I use tmux version 2.1.

Answer (score 62):

This looks like a change in tmux in 2.0 -> 2.1

I've replaced

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window off
```

with just

```
set-option -g mouse on
```

and everything seems ok

Comment: `mouse on` configures the following: `The default key bindings allow the mouse to be used to select and resize panes, to copy text and to change window using the status line.`, so it's the equivalent of setting `mouse-select-pane`, `mouse-resize-pane` and `mouse-select-window` as `on`.  Probably close enough to the original configuration; though not exactly the same.

Comment: All these years I was driving with the handbrake on.

Answer (score 2):

mode-mouse isn't support on tmux. Try use on ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g mouse on
```

and run on terminal

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Work so good on my computer, it can scroll, change panes...

Comment: it was obsolete and simplified